# angular js add value of selected checkbox to an array

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller

This is not that a twisted problem but somehow confuses me.

HTML-A
This view renders a screen name (ex:Home) and all associated navigations with it.

```
<div ng-repeat="content in Data.ContentDataList">
   <div>{{content.Name}</div>
        <div>
            <li ng-repeat="nav in content.NavigationList" >{{nav.Text}}</li>
       </div>
  </div>
```

HTML-B
In the same view this renders a list of all navigation available

```
<dl>
   <dd ng-repeat="item in selectedItems">
   <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isSelected" ng-click="addNav(item.contentData.Name )" />{{ item.contentData.Name }}
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Controller

```
app.controller('NavController', ['$scope','Service','$routeParams', function ($scope, Service, $routeParams) {
$scope.items = [];
$scope.Data = [];
$scope.selectedItems = [];

$scope.addNav = function() {

     ????? Fire an event to add selected navigation from HTML-B to HTML-A ??????
};

Service.getData(xyz).then(function (results) {

    $scope.Data = results.data;
    $scope.items = $scope.Data.ContentDataList;

    for(var i=0; i<$scope.items.length; i++) {

     var mycl = {'contentData' : $scope.items[i], 
         'isSelected' : false };
     $scope.selectedItems.push(mycl);
    };
});
```

Comment: the controller needs  addNav function where a checked checkbox name is  added to to the ng-repeat="nav in content.NavigationList".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the addNav function;

```
$scope.addNav = function(cbName) {
    content.NavigationList.push({text:cbName});
};
```